# Python can't access the Internet on Windows Server 2003

Tags: networking, python, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to install the [requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) on windows 2003 with Python 3.4.0 I have also tried Python 3.2 and got the exact same result.

When I try an install using pip I get the following error

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement requests
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for requests
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\pip\pip.log
```

When I try with easy_install i get the following error

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>easy_install requests
Searching for requests
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'requests' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [WinError 10061] No connection could     be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for requests
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('requests')
```

I managed to install requests on Python 3.2 from source however when I try and use requests on it fails with the error message

> File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.2.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 378, in send
>       raise ProxyError(e)
>   requests.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

It seems as if Python doesn't have access to the network.
The Windows Firewall is turned off, the machine doesn't have a virus scanner, proxy or third party firewall. The machine can access the network/Internet with other applications.

I have also run the script I have written on another machine and everything works as I expect it to. Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Control panel/Internet option/connections/lan settings untick everything

Comment: Thanks @rob that solved the issue, can you add it as an answer so I can mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proxy settings seem to be stopping you script accessing the internet.

Goto Control panel/Internet options/Connections/Lan Settings 
and untick/confirm everything.